# Delphi 2010 - Hydra plugin with sharemem

Tags: delphi

I converted my D2010 EXE into hydra plugin DLL. This DLL is using few other DLL functions which contains string parameters. So, i used sharemem as the first unit.

I then created a Hydra host application and loaded this plugin. Forms built into the plugin are loaded.  But I am getting some Access violations and the application flickering issues while closing the main application. i tried to debug both the plugin aswell as host. but couldn't go further after some stage.

Any ideas on fixing this would be very useful

Thanks 
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

There is hardly any information in this question useful for solving it. You need to be more specific for a specific solution. However, I can give you some problem-solving tips for this kind of problem:

1. Make an experimental copy of your application. Progressivly remove pieces of code and retest the load-plugin and close behaviour until you either reach stability or both your host application and the plugin are trivial stubs. At this point you have localised the cause of your troubles.
2. Make sure that the host application is compiled with "Packages" turned on.
3. Use a tool like DependencyWalker to determine the list of run-time packages used by both binaries.
4. Check run-time package list for both the host and the plugin. The basic idea is that there should be no common unit which is instantiated twice due to the fact that its owning runtime package is missing either from the host's list or the plugin's list.